# What term to use instead of "Company" to represent, well, a company

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm in the process of (re) designing a software product, and I'm attempting to find the right term to use. Right now, our product has been targeted at a few different industries that operate on a distributor-dealer infrastructure, and our software has been sold primarily to dealers. As a result, we have come to refer to the company (or companies) that are represented within a single database as "dealers", even though they may, in fact, be distributors and the dealers are actually their customers.

The package is expanding in scope and is now going to be targeted at other organizations that may not operate under this model, so the term "dealer" is becoming increasingly diluted. As a result, we are attempting to find a suitable term that is both generic enough not to be unintuitive, but also specific enough so as not to be easily confused with other parts of the database. In other words, simply calling them "Company" could be confusing because users already have other "companies" with which they conduct business entered into the system, and "Company" is the term used to describe them.

So far, only "Company" and "Business" have been found to be suitably generic, but I'm not sure if they're specific enough. I know that software like QuickBooks refers to them as a "Company", but I'm curious if there is something better suited.

**EDIT**: The database in question is the *customer's* database, not our own. We design the database and the application, but it's their data. Perhaps a little more information will be helpful, as there seems to be some confusion about what I'm talking about. I was under the impression that people reading my question could actually read my mind, but in case that isn't true:

As stated above, our current model uses the term "Dealer". In our database, we have a `Dealer` table that stores information about the dealer (or dealers) that our customer runs. In turn, we have a `Customer` table in their database that represents their customers, and a `DealerId` column in that table to associate a customer to a given dealership (some of our clients have multiple dealerships that they run out of the same database in order to share other things, such as product lists). What I'm looking for is an alternative to the term `Dealer`, as our target markets are no longer solely businesses that could be considered "dealerships".

`Company` would work, but I am concerned with our interaction with the customer becoming confused by mixing usage of the word "Company" for their company with other "companies" that they might interact with.

Comment: Aren't they all just "customers" from the point of view of *your* company? Or "clients" if you want to sound more upmarket?

Comment: *Company* is fine.  You'll injure none of your customers' self-respect, plus you can define it to mean whatever you want - sounds win-win to me.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue that the users conduct business with other "companies".  The user is a company, and the user's dealings are with other companies.  Is it really likely that the user will accidentally identify himself with another company?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, but this is about *their* database. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @drɱ65δ: While "Company" is a valid answer, the concern is that there is a distinction--from a data model perspective--between a "Company" that is our customer (but I'm hesitant to call it Customer since this is *their* database and *their* customers are other people) and a "Company" that they interact with. I'm not so much concerned with the user accidentally identifying with another company, but rather the fact that we're going to be talking about two entirely different tables.

Comment: If it's their database and these are their customers, then it should be "customer", IMO.

Comment: Thoughts: Business, Company, Corporation, Firm, Organization, Entity, Person, Incorporation. I tend towards Firm or Organization, as they are more generic (both can include other business arrangements such as partnerships, the latter can include government entities).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No, these are their databases and the table refers to *them*. Say, for example, I own company ABC and company XYZ. These are two different (but perhaps related) companies, and each of these companies will have separate customer lists. Our current model has a `Dealer` table and a `DealerId` column in the customer table that identifies a customer with a given dealer. What I'm looking for is a more generic alternative to "Dealer".

Comment: If it's a container that holds customers, then "company" is probably right.

Comment: Change dealer to *us* and companies to *them*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Really trying to find nouns, not pronouns.

Comment: There isn't a single word meaning *our company* as opposed to *the other company* in English.  Are you sure that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @drɱ65δ: Yes, and "it doesn't exist" is a perfectly suitable answer :)

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Comment: @drɱ65δ: Post that as an answer (with a little more elaboration) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that there isn't a single word meaning *our company* as opposed to *another company* in English.  If it's too confusing to use just plain *company*, then you may have to come up with some form of *us*, *this company*, *our company*, etc. on the one hand, and *affiliate* or *associate companies* (or *client*, if that's applicable) for the companies "our company" is working with.

Comment: +1. We've decided to go with "Company" to refer to our client's company and "Organization" to refer to other companies that they might do business with.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If one client of yours deals business through multiple dealers/companies/entities, an apt term would be **channels**. Another good potential is **locations**.

EDIT: You could use **distributors**, but it seems the reason for your question is that either your clients' businesses are expanding beyond simple dealing/distribution, or your clientele is expanding beyond those who exclusively deal/distribute.

Comment: Thanks, but the term does not have anything to do with their relationship to us. This is a term for *our client* in *their database*. It shouldn't make any reference to us or our relationship.

Comment: It doesn't. It refers to *their* channels of distribution, or *their* locations.

Answer (score 0):

"Buyer" perhaps? Seems suitably generic.

Comment: The database in question is for the customer, not for us, so I'm not sure "buyer" is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Other synonyms I would use are **concern** and **enterprise**.

Answer (score 0):

The context suggests that you don't really need a synonym for "Company" but for "Company which purchased our software". Candidates would seem to include "Software Licensee" and "Data Owner".

Comment: No, what I need is a synonym for "Company" ;) This needs to represent their company/organization from *their* perspective, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you really want is to distinguish "myself" from "others like me". Perhaps something reflexive, like "Self" or "My Company", is a better choice"? Or brand it with the company's name?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that everything be, fundamentally, a *Company*.

The one that owns the database can be called the MasterCompany.  (alternately - Owner, Main, Primary, etc.)

All the others can be called OtherCompanies.  (alternately - Ancillary, Secondary, Partner, etc.)

You may even rethink the database structure and ask yourself if there really is a need for them to be separate concepts.  Perhaps everything should be reflected in a single Company table with just a flag or type or something to identify the type.

Comment: Organization meets the first criteria (generic enough), but it's not specific enough. I need something that clearly identifies that these records belong to *your* company ("your" pertaining to our customer, in this case).

Comment: It sounds like you have different kinds of companies/organizations/businesses in your database.  Either there is something that differentiates type X (dealer/distributer) from type Y (the other companies) or there isn't.  If there is, quantifying that difference might help you come up with a good name.

Comment: type X is our customer (but remember, this is *their* database, so it represents "them"), type Y would be companies that they have some sort of business relationship with but are *not* a part of their company.

Comment: I see.  In that case I would call X "Company", meaning "the company that owns this database".   I would call Y something else:  "Vendor/Client/Partner/etc." as appropriate.

Comment: I would agree with that, except for the fact that all of these other "companies" could be any of those things (and more). I really need something that's just as generic as "company", unfortunately.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult here, but these records are *fundamentally different*. Storing them in the same table is out of the question. The "owner" company and "other" companies must be separate terms. That's why I'm searching for an alternative.

Comment: Even if they need to be stored in different table, that would not preclude you from naming those tables as I suggested (MasterCompany and OtherCompanies or whatever).  Of course it's just a suggestion!     My only point was that a company is a company, and although you might need to store different data for different /kinds/ of companies, that doesn't mean you need to come up with arbitrarily unique terms for them.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but my question really is one of language; I'm not looking for database design guidance :) The information about the database was simply to provide background, as requested by another user. The question is, and has been, about looking for an appropriate synonym for "company".

Answer (score -1):

You might clarify in the question the sort of documents and the company levels where the terminology you seek will be used.  *I.e.*, company internal *vs.* external, verbal *vs.* written, documentation *vs.* contracts.

Because you apparently wish to refer unambiguously to two different levels of clients, concerns, buyers or customers, it might be reasonable to designate **'primary'** and **'secondary'** as terms referring to the two levels of customers.

The acronym VAR (value-added reseller) is often used to refer to an intermediate level of software distributors, packagers, dealers, resellers, or vendors, who are clients of software companies with, in turn, clients of their own.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question.